# How to post back collection of DropDown List values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I have the following:

**View model**:

```
public ICollection<SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption> SelectConfigurableOptions { get; set; }
```

**SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption**:

```
public class BaseConfigurableDataSyncOption
{
    public string OptionText { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
}

public class SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption : BaseConfigurableDataSyncOption
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> OptionValue { get; set; }
}
```

**.cshtml:**

```
@foreach (SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption option in Model.SelectConfigurableOptions)
{
    <div class="span6">
        <h4>@option.OptionText?</h4>
        <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => {WHAT TO DO}, new SelectList(option.OptionValue, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "m-wrap span12" })</p>
    </div>
}
```

The problem I have is posting the values of the selected drop down lists back to the controller. With a normal drop down list, I would declare a variable to store the value and bind the DropDownList to that which would be fine but because I can have any number posting back, I don't know what to do.

I am happy to be told I'm doing this completely wrong but essentially I am trying to allow a list of dropdownlists to be presented on the front end.

Comment: Can I ask how it's unclear what I am asking. The bottom paragraph clearly states this. If it doesn't please state what isn't clear and I will clarify as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the BeginCollectionItem Html Helper.  We use this with success on a daily basis for generating a collection of Html inputs (regardless of type):

https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem

Nuget Package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/

Comment: Taking a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort this so am posting for future queries on the subject:

I changed my class in the collection to this:

```
public class SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption : BaseConfigurableDataSyncOption
{
    //Added this in to track the selected option
    public string SelectedOptionValue { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> OptionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Changed the `ICollection` to a `List` in my `ViewModel`:

```
public List<SelectConfigurableDataSyncOption> SelectConfigurableOptions { get; set; }
```

Then changed my `.cshtml` file to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SelectConfigurableOptions.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="span6">
        <h4>@Model.SelectConfigurableOptions[i].OptionText?</h4>
        <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.SelectConfigurableOptions[i].SelectedOptionValue, new SelectList(Model.SelectConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "m-wrap span12" })</p>
    </div>
}
```

This gave me access to `Model.SelectConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue` which allows the value to post back to the controller.